# How can I create a Sys.UI.Control from inside another Sys.UI.Control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm creating a somewhat complex clientside UI control, and the idea is that this control in itself contains other controls based on properties applied to it.

I want to create these child controls from inside the initialize() overridden member, since I have to produce the child DOM elements to which these child controls will be attached, but the documentation for $create() states that you shouldn't create components from inside the initialize() function.

Now, my question is, what do I do? What's the best strategy to use here?

Comment: Even though I provided my own answer on how to circumvent the problem, I still would like a better one, so I started a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided that only the complex clientside UI control should inherit from Sys.UI.Control, and that all objects inside it, along with the HTML they generate, should not, and thus should not be created using $create().

Although not a real answer to the question, this is a possibly solution.